# pass Multilple values in struts2 action with one param name

Tags: struts2, action

I would like to pass Multiple parameters for single param in action tag.

Ex:

`<action name="question" class="com.xxx.xxx.action">`
   `<param name="hint">abc</param>`
   `<result name="success">Answers.jsp</result>`
`</action>`

I have getters and setters for hint (String) variable in my action.

Currently i can be able to get parameter value for hint variable as abc if i send one.

I would like to send multiple parameters for same variable(hint)

ex: `<param name="hint">abc, xyz</param>`

how can achieve the above.

Thanks in advance
Raju

Answer (score 2):

I found the best answer here (look at the bottom of the page):
http://www.coderanch.com/t/494764/Struts/define-String-array-param-tag

If for some reason the link is broken, here is what you do:

```
<s:param name="queryType" value="new java.lang.String[]{'PRIMARY','SECONDARY'}"/>
```

If you are submitting a `<s:form>`, you just use the same NAME for multiple parameters and Struts2 automatically creates the String Array!

Just remember to create the correct setter and getter in your action, for example:

```
    public void setQueryType(String[] queryType){
        this.queryType = queryType;
    }
```

Notice that you declare String[ ] as an Array, that's all!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that, apart from the obvious hacks 
For example, just write the above in you mapping and in your action convert the string to a array

```
  String[] getHintsArray() {
       return getParam("hint").split("\\s*,\\s*");
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I tried in similar way it worked but i thought is there any other way to do it in struts2 ?